# How to find Key Constraint in 1:M cardinality Entity set?

Tags: database-design, constraint

I have a problem in identifying the key constraints of the Entity set.

As in the relation, the key constraint should be from M-side. 
But here, in this case, according to me Father is the key constraint.
So for this, the relation is 1:M. In this case, it doesn't satisfy Father to be the key constraint.

[image: Father to Son]